# json_encode works in php, but null in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, null, json

I'm just learning php, and I am trying to parse some files I have, and then send the information to javascript. This is my php:

```
$datesArray = readFile();
echo json_encode($datesArray);
```

This echoes:

```
["120102000000","120102000500","120102001000","120102001500","120102002000","120102002500","120102003000"]
```

Which is what I want. However, my javascript, which looks like this:

```
var dates = <?php echo json_encode($datesArray); ?>;
console.log(dates);
```

keeps giving `dates` back as null, and I am not sure why. I have tried encoding the array as utf-8, and I have tried using `jQuery.parseJSON` which also did not work.

Thanks--

Comment: Not that I expect it to change much, but try `<?= json_encode($datesArray ?>;`

Comment: @Seiyria I'm sorry I'm not familiar with that syntax, do you mean like this: `var dates <?= json_encode($datesArray) ?>;` ? I keep getting a syntax error back :/

Comment: When you look at the source code with the JS output, what you see? Can you see what if being echoed by php?

Comment: @Isouza Okay, I see, I'm getting `var dates = ;`. How do I tell Javascript how to interpret the `<?php ?>` tags?

Comment: wait... what kind of server are you running on?

Answer (score 0):

Just checking, but is that JavaScript with PHP in a `.js` file? By default, Apache only runs PHP in files ending in `.php` so that would mean your PHP is getting parsed as plain text by the server.

If that is the case, the easiest solution is to run that part of the script in some `<script>` tags.

Alternatively you *could* make Apache try to serve `.js` files as PHP file via Mime-Types; but that is really a mess not worth implementing.

Comment: This is all in a `.php` file. The full block loks like `<script>
var dates = <?php echo json_encode($datesArray) ?>; console.log(dates);</script>`